# android app not registering onTouch

Tags: android, android-layout, ontouchlistener, android-event

**This is my layout file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <!-- will add other views later -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is my custom view**

```
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        ….//draw some shapes
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            float xTouch = event.getX();
            float yTouch = event.getY();

            String str = "(" + xTouch + "," + yTouch + ")";
            System.out.println(str);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**This is main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View myView = new MyView(this, data);
        FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        container.addView(myView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**PROBLEM**

The app is not registering my touch events for custom view. The view displays all the contents of `onDraw`, but when I click, onTouch is not registering. I try putting a break point at the `if` in onTouch, but it's never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be that you are not registering the onTouchListener to the view in a constructor, im not really sure but [here onTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) is a method you override like onDraw for a view, maybe that would suit you better

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){

return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need call setOnTouchListener() to register the callback of touch event.